# Reshape data into image ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3072) into shape (32,3)

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 2d

l'm trying to reshape data into image as follow. Everything work well, except the last line code :

```
y[i]=image2
```

l want to store the result in a new variable `y`. I got this error at the line code `y[i]=image2` :

```
**ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3072) into shape (32,3)**
```

My code:

```
    from numpy import *
    import cPickle
    import scipy.io as io
    from random import randrange

      y = [len(v) for v in batch_1.values()]

   Y = zeros([len(batch_1['data'][:]),3072])
   for i in range(len(batch_1['data'][:])):  #len() =10000  
        image = batch_1['data'][i]
        image.shape = (3, 32, 32)
        image_result = copy(image.transpose((1, 2, 0)))
        image_result = reshape(image_result, (1, 3072))
        Y[i] = image_result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the extra dimension. Replace `(1, 3072)` with `3072`

**EDIT**:

There are more problems with your code as well. The `Y`is not defined, and by line `image_result= reshape(image2, (1, 3072))`  I think you actually meant:

```
image2 = reshape(image_result, (1, 3072))
```

The new code should look like this (not tested):

```
from numpy import *
import cPickle
import scipy.io as io
from random import randrange

Y = zeros([len(batch_1['data'][:]),3072])

for i in range(len(batch_1['data'][:])):  #len() =10000  
    image = batch_1['data'][i]
    image.shape = (3, 32, 32)
    image_result = copy(image.transpose((1, 2, 0)))
    image2 = reshape(image_result, (1, 3072))
    y[i]=image2
```

Comment: l got this variable y in not defined

Comment: can l initialize   y[i]=zeros(1,3072)  like this ?

Comment: I think by this line : `image_result= reshape(image2, (1, 3072))` you actually meant  `image2= reshape(image_result, (1, 3072))`

Comment: @ahmedmazari check my new answer

Comment: @ahmedmazari you know we can't run the code since we don't have the `batch_1` !

Comment: no, l got this error  Y = zeros(len(batch_1['data'][:]),3072)   data type not understood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126840/discussion-between-yugi-and-ahmedmazari).